# Is it necessary for Laravel to have Laravel collective html tags than ordinary HTML 5 tags?

Tags: laravel-5

So I'm building a website using Laravel, so I am confused regarding which tags should I use. Pure Laravel collective html tags or plain HTML5 tags, what are the pros and cons?

Comment: You can use pure HTML 5. Using Collective makes even you code html in Laravel style and provides some functions to make things easy. Ultimately even collective converts code into HTML

Comment: if u use collective, u have less pain, in edit and show view. the laravel itself populates the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary, You can use plain HTML code.

**pros:**

```
when you have a lot of forms and edit views 

the checkboxes, select boxes and radio buttons are much easier to work with 
Laravel Collective
```

**cons:**

```
yet another dependencie
```

Comment: then why they created collective HTML tags

Comment: the pros and cons of collective html tags

Comment: It is easier to work with them. But you are not forced to use them.